# High Charts fails to add series dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using HighCharts for the first time and it's proving to be difficult to find sources to help me with this problem.

I am trying to display multiple charts with different numbers of series. Rather than set up multiple options templates I want to use just one and use a function to customize the options object each time. Here I've provided mock data for what one of the charts will look like as received from the API. In the application I plan on feeding it from HTML.

I keep running into various problems due to my lack of understanding of HighCharts, right now I am just going around in circles fixing one problem only for a past problem to pop-up again I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
This is my Class:

```
export class CompletenessTabComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('chartTarget') chartTarget: ElementRef;

  chart: Highcharts.ChartObject;

  dataObj = {"id":0,
    "tableName":"d1 vs d2",
    "data":{"d1Count":[50,45,55,60,70],
      "d2Count":[40,32,55,58,33],
      "Errors":[2,3,4,1,0]},
    "dates":[20180927,20180928,20181001,20181002,20181003]
  };

  constructor() { }

  setHighChartOptions(data, seriesNames, chartTitle ): any {
    count = 1;
    highChartOptions.title.text = chartTitle;
    highChartOptions.xAxis.data = data.dates;
    this.chart.series[0].setData(this.dataObj.data[0]);
    Object.keys(data.data).forEach((key) =>
      this.chart.addSeries({
        name: seriesNames[count],
        data: data.data[key],
        type: 'line'
      }) count ++
    );
    return highChartOptions;
  }
  getHighChartOptions(){
    return highChartOptions;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.chart = chart(this.chartTarget.nativeElement, this.setHighChartOptions(this.dataObj, ['d1', 'd2', 'error'], this.dataObj.tableName));
    Object.keys(this.dataObj.data).forEach(key =>
    console.log(key, this.dataObj.data[key]))
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

}

const highChartOptions = {
  colors:
    ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],

  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: null,
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    itemStyle: {
      fontSize: '10px',
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    valuePrefix: '$'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'date',
    data: [],
    title: 'date'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      align: 'middle',
      rotation: 0,
      text: ''
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      shadow: false
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: '',
    data: [null]
  }]
};
```

A few errors I keep receiving are:

> in setHighChartOptions() : Cannot read property 'series' of undefined (at, this.chart.series[0]), & cannot read 'keys' of undefined (at the start of the ForEach loop).

I believe the big issue is the chart object is undefined which doesn't make sense since I've instantiated it at the top of the class and then onInit I set the chart options.

I hope you will be able spot my errors and assist me. Thank You.

Comment: Your `highChartOptions` is a `const` you can't modify a `const` just remove this prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, it's because you're trying to refer to series which is not already defined. Actually, if you calling the `setHighchartsOptions` for a first time, your chart is not defined yet.

In order to make it works, please try to init the chart first (even could be the empty chart, without any data), and then call another methods on `Chart` object, like `addSeries`. Something like that, but i didn't saw whole your app, so it's hard to write completely adjusted solution.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.chart = chart(this.chartTarget.nativeElement, {});
    this.chart.update(this.setHighChartOptions(this.dataObj, ['d1', 'd2', 'error'], this.dataObj.tableName))
    Object.keys(this.dataObj.data).forEach(key =>
    console.log(key, this.dataObj.data[key]))
  }
```

Comment: Yes I figured this out as well. I realized that the set Options function was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must be careful to use import correctly all js package in your Angular project:

```
import { chart } from 'highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

Also, you must check does your package installed correctly with "npm"?

After all, As my point of view, this example can help you to better understand how to use "highcharts" package in your project, other configs depend on the version of "highcharts" you are using it.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { chart } from 'highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Highcharts Sample';

  @ViewChild('chartTarget') chartTarget: ElementRef;

  chart: Highcharts.ChartObject;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const options: Highcharts.Options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Sample Title'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Top Test', 'Test 2', 'Test3']
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Fox Rex'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Tomi',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
      }, {
        name: 'Alex',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
      }]
    };

    this.chart = chart(this.chartTarget.nativeElement, options);
  }

  addSeries(){
    this.chart.addSeries({
      name:'Test',
      data:[2,3,7]
    })    
  }
}
```

And HTML template of sample:

```
<div #chartTarget>
  chart target sample
</div>
```

Also, you must serve data to highcharts as the format is standard for that, check JSON sample data format in examples in highcharts website.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and see if this makes the difference

Comment: Hi this doesn't work when I want to show multiple charts on the same page. Will I need to define a new chart object for each chart?

Comment: I decided to create a seperate component to which I will feed the data and I can define a single options structure there that can be used to create multiple charts, hopefully that works

Comment: One good way is to make a new component for any of them, although you can show more than one in one component. If the type of chart is not important for you to please check D3 and C3 charts instead of the Highchart. Also, for chart object, you can have one object and overwrite that for any of your charts.

Comment: I was looking at this but how do I use the addSeries() Function to add to opitons before setting the chart object for a structure like the mock data. That's where I run into issues with the chart being instantiated =/